# How to iterate through only the text box elements in the form using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form  which contains 4 text fields  when the button is clicked 
we should see that atleast one of the textfield should contain the value and the form should get submitted 
and the form also contains the Button which of input type too .I want only textbox field  values

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){

$(":input").each(function(){
  if($(this).value!=''){
    $("#myform").submit();

 }

});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) for the selector, [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) down to ones that have a value and check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
  if($(":text").filter(function(){ return this.value!=''; }).length)
    $("#myform").submit();
});
```

this checks if *any* aren't empty, and if that's the case, submits the form once.

---

And here's an alternative that checks on `<form>` submit, compliments of doug's comment:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  if(!$(":text").filter(function(){ return this.value!=''; }).length)
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I still would bind to `submit` instead of button click, but the filter is a really nice touch!

Comment: I want to submit only if there is atleast one field entered

Comment: @Someone - This would do that, for example the second one's checking for any that have a non-empty values, if there are any it keeps submitting `if(!1)` wouldn't `return false` for example, if none had a value, then `if(!0)` *would* `return false;`, stopping the submit from happening.

Answer (score 3):

First, bind to `form` submit not button click. If a user hits `enter/return` in a field, it will submit your form without the checks:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
  var fields = $(this).find(':text'),
      cancel = true;

  fields.each(function (i, el) {
    if (el.value) {
      cancel = false;
      return false; // exit this loop
    }
  });

  if (cancel) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit since all fields are blank
  }      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.  I've replaced your `:input` selector with `:text` to only get textboxes.  Also you were calling `.value` on the jquery object rather than using the `.val()` method.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    $(":text").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() !='') {
            $("#myform").submit();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Like @joshperry's original answer, this could submit the form multiple times.

Comment: @Doug Neiner - Thanks, I've updated my answer to return false to break out of the each statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input:text` selector to get all the textboxes.

```
$("input:text")
```

Comment: This would submit the form multiple times :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess his code was flawed. I was answering the question not doing a code review...

Comment: You can just add a `return false` within your each iteration and jquery will automatically treat that the same as a `break` in a traditional loop.

Comment: Again, I was just regurgitating his code. So I've just removed everything that doesn't answer the specific question.